# UITextField wrong content width when isSecureTextEntry property set to true

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextfield

I have two UITextFields configured like that:

```
let yellowPasswordTextField = UITextField()
view.addSubview(yellowPasswordTextField)
yellowPasswordTextField.placeholder = "Type"
yellowPasswordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
yellowPasswordTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
yellowPasswordTextField.topToSuperview(offset: 30) // TinyConstraints api
yellowPasswordTextField.leftToSuperview()
yellowPasswordTextField.text = "mmmmmm"

let greenTextField = UITextField()
view.addSubview(greenTextField)
greenTextField.placeholder = "Type"
greenTextField.isSecureTextEntry = false
greenTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
greenTextField.topToSuperview(offset: 60)
greenTextField.leftToSuperview()
greenTextField.text = "mmmmmm"
```

Please notice that both are configured exactly the same (including text), the only difference is that the first one has isSecureTextEntry property enabled while the second one has this property disabled.

And here is the result layout:

[image]

Why first UITextField has width that is exactly the same like for text field with isSecureTextEntry disabled (the one below)? Is there any way to force first text field to adjust its width to actual content - bullets replacing original text?

It's problematic because I would like to add rightView for showing/hiding password just after textfield content.

Comment: You could use a fixed-width font... using the font you have now, if you enter `iiiiii` it's going to be much shorter than `mmmmmm` or `wwwwww`. That's simply how non-fixed-width fonts display.

Comment: That's not an option in my case. I have to keep fonts consistent with the rest of app.

Comment: Well, I think you're out of luck. How would you want to display variable-width fonts? If you jumped through hoops to display your own "dots," a password of "..ii..ii.." is going to look much different than "WWMMHHWW" (as you can see here). You say *"I would like to add rightView for showing/hiding password just after textfield content"* ... So do you really need the "dots" to display at the same width as the "plain" text? Or do you just need the "plain" text to display aligned with the right-end of the dots?

Comment: What I need is button at the right end to switch between "dotted" and normal text. And I want it to be always just after text (with some spacing of course) in both dotted and normal mode. In "normal" mode everything is fine, but in "dotted" mode when I start typing f.e. "wwwwww" the spacing between button and last dot is increasing with each character (beacuse "w" is wider than dot)